# Update selected item in vuetify navigation drawer while scrolling vertical

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I've implemented a navigation drawer in Vuetify that scrolls towards an anchor in the same page.
When I click an anchor it gets selected and this works just fine.
However now I want to update the selected item in the navigation drawer as soon as the user scroll in a different sections.

```
      <v-navigation-drawer
          app
          clipped
  >
    <v-list shaped>
      <v-list-item-group v-model="item" color="primary" selectedItem=0>

      <v-list-item
              v-for="section in sections"
              :key="section.title"
              @click="$vuetify.goTo(section.id, 0, 0)"
              >
        <v-list-item-icon>
          <v-icon>{{ section.icon }}</v-icon>
        </v-list-item-icon>

        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title v-text="section.title"></v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
      </v-list-item-group>
    </v-list>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
```

I've looked in the documentation and it looks like I can use Intersection observer (https://vuetifyjs.com/directives/intersect) for this but I don't know how to bind it to the v-list-item.

Do you have a clue on how to bind this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem.

> V-intersect shows an element is being visited. List item has an
> active-class prop and 'input-value' prop to state the item is active.
> I'll try to see if I can piece these together.

I started with those 3 thoughts and was able to solve this problem with those 3: v-intersect, input-value prop of list-item, and 'color' prop of list-item. I can define an active-class if I want, but color is good enough for me.

References:

1. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/directives/intersect/
2. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists/

I used vuex to solve this easily. I'm not fond of props/events to communicate with parent/child components. So you need one state each for all v-list-items. Set the color of v-list-item to something distinctive. [2]

Now for each of the components, set up a v-intersect. Following the docs @ [1], the `onIntersect` function will mutate the respective vuex state earlier. Note that from `entries[0].isIntersecting`, the `isIntersecting` is part of entries[0], don't change that.

Done, now when you scroll down, you should see the nav items update to color in real time.

---

Previous thoughts:

---

I wanted to write a comment, but I need 50 'points'. I'm fairly new at asking/answering questions here. I do read a lot.

Anyways, I'm in the same situation now. I'm starting to look into this. Intersect seems like the answer, but not quite at the same time. If you have found the answer, then please share with me :)

Obviously, there must be a way to do this since VueJS docs has implemented this. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html. Nav on left has highlighted title/subtitle based on scroll.

V-intersect shows an element is being visited. List item has an
active-class prop and 'input-value' prop to state the item is active.
I'll try to see if I can piece these together.

I know we can cheat by using vue-scrollactive, but I don't want to do that yet.